# Javascript function not being executed in $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `fillOpenOrders` that I call via `require`. The function is then supposed to be called in `$(document).ready()` along with some other functions. The problem is that `fillOpenOrders` does not get called. It is ignored and other functions are executed normally.

I have a DataTable with `Id` of "mainTable. When i click on any row, the following code should be executed.

```
    var functions = require("./functions");
    var openOrdersT = require("./src/openOrders");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mainTable tr').on('click', function () {
            
            var id = $(this).find('td:first').text();
            document.getElementById("coin-name").innerHTML = id;
            openOrdersT.fillOpenOrders();
            functions.fillNavPrices();
            
            widget.onChartReady(function () {
                var chart = widget.activeChart();
                chart.setSymbol(id);

            });
        });
    });
```

Other functions (`fillNavPrices` etc.) are working normally.

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

The code for `openOrdersT` looks like this.

```
module.exports{
fetchOO: function(){...},
fillOpenOrders: function(){
//It doesn't matter what is inside here. I tried with a simple alert or console.log function here. 
//Function is meant to update a DataTable with new data.
}
}
```

Meanwhile `fetchOO()` works like expected.

Comment: How is require being resolved? When you run `console.log(functions);` what do you see in the console? It's possible that the require is not resolving properly for that file but it is for the openOrders require

Comment: @redroot if it had not resolved properly, though, it would create errors and the subsequent commands would not be executed, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Razmooo please post the code from `openOrdersT` or at least the `fillOpenOrders` method.

Comment: I updated the question @GabyakaG.Petrioli